# Jersey POJOMappingFeature to convert null to empty string?

Tags: java, json, jersey

I'm using Jersey 1.18 and I have POJOMappingFeature enabled.
I would like all incoming & outgoing JSON values to be converted from `null` to an empty string.

How to configure the mapping?
I've searched web but was unable to find what I'm looking for.

from my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.abc.restControllers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

and an example of a controller:

```
package com.abc.restControllers;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.abc.restModals.Place.Place_descInfo_Request;
import com.abc.restModals.Place.Place_descInfo_Response;

@Path("/place")
public class PlaceController {

    @POST
    @Path("/place_descInfo")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Place_descInfo_Response place_descInfo(Place_descInfo_Request req) {

        return new Place_descInfo_Response(req);
    }

} // End class
```

Comment: Are using Jackson as JSON processor https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers? Can you check if you have the jackson library dependency in your project class path? If so it's pretty easy to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome), you can write a custom serializer for your pojos. For instance:

```
public class FooSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Foo> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(final Foo value, final JsonGenerator jgen,
        final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException
    {
        if (value.bar() == null) {
            jgen.writeString("");
        } else {
            jgen.writeString(value.bar());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, on your `Foo` object:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = FooSerializer.class)
public class Foo {
    private String bar;

    public String bar() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

You can also create custom deserializers by extending `JsonDeserializer` to handle incoming nulls, or put a filter in place to parse the body?

Comment: This answer is the "most" correct. and the cleanest (i.e if this was graded, your prof would give it a A).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jackson and have got access to `ObjectMapper` you can configure it in a way you want.

You can set a null value serializer that writes empty strings for null objects, and register a String deserializer which treats empty strings in JSON as nulls.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonNull {

    public static class Bean {
        public String field1;
        public String field2;

        public Bean() {}

        public Bean(String field1, String field2) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field2 = field2;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bean{" +
                    "field1='" + field1 + '\'' +
                    ", field2='" + field2 + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Bean bean = new Bean(null, "value");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(Object value,
                                  JsonGenerator jgen,
                                  SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
                jgen.writeString("");
            }
        });
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(String.class, new JsonDeserializer<String>() {
            @Override
            public String deserialize(JsonParser jp,
                                      DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                String string = jp.getValueAsString();
                return string.isEmpty() ? null : string;
            }
        });
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Bean.class));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"field1":"","field2":"value"}
Bean{field1='null', field2='value'}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Jersey maillist:

One more thing: to ignore the null values, you will probably also
need to provide your own Jackson ObjectMapper provider
with the Jackson SerializationConfig.Feature WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES [3]
set to false. Please see [2] for details on how to hook your custom
ObjectMapper into Jersey.

HTH,

~Jakub

[2]http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/samples/jacksonjsonprovider/1.6-ea06/jacksonjsonprovider-1.6-ea06-project.zip
[3]http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig.Feature.html#WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES

I think this is your answer.

Comment: WRITE_NULL_PROPERTY looks like a deprecated way to configure serialization to skip writing null values. I believe the question was about converting null values to empty strings.

Comment: Yep, deprecated but still working. Also re-read my post, setting this property is only half of work.